# What is the maximum amount of characters fit into the nametag of a DotA 2 object?

Tags: dota-2

Name tags can be purchased from the shop in DotA 2 store. How many characters does a nametag allow me to use on an object such as a courier?

Comment: In Team Fortress 2, a name tag has to be 40 characters or less in length. I suspect this is true for DotA2 as well, but I cannot confirm that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is 15 characters. I used a nametag on a Chaos Knight axe and called it "Axe of Disarray" and I am pretty sure that I remember that took up the exact maximum amount of characters as I was playing around with various different names trying to input ones longer than 15 character which I was unable to do due to this length constraint.